# iOS:About [UIDocumentInteractionController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:inView:animated:]

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

Now I have **some files** in the Document folder,and I use `[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:myFileA];` to get the doc controller and the I use `[UIDocumentInteractionController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:inView:animated:];` to present one options sheet.So now I have **2** questions:

**[1]** How can I give the doc controller **more than one** File URLs? Is there anyway to achieve this?

**[2]** I find that the method `[UIDocumentInteractionController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:inView:animated:];` works fine in **iOS6 or later**, but **not** in ***iOS5.1***. Why?

Hope your answers.Thanks a lot first!

Comment: 1) No. 2) What exactly is the problem you're seeing on 5.1?

Comment: @omz I call [UIDocumentInteractionController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:inView:animated:]; and the result is NO.Failed!

Comment: Perhaps you don't have the same apps installed on the 5.1 device/simulator you're testing with?

Comment: @omz And The iOS5.1 ipad has the Applications such us email.

Comment: What type of document are you working with?

Answer (score 0):

1st question: I don't think you can do that, with that particular API, looking at the documentation.

2nd question: As stated by the documentation,

> The options
>   menu may not be displayed in cases where there are no appropriate
>   items to include in the menu.

These include files with unknown extensions. iOS6+ however does handdle this well.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar experience to your problem in **[2]** while testing `presentOptionsMenuFromRect:inView:animated:` on iOS 5.1 and 6.0. In iOS 6.0 I got a full menu with apps and other options depending on the file. In iOS 5.1 I had a somewhat different experience than you: I got a menu with only one option.

The solution for me was to use `presentOpenInMenuFromRect:inView:animated:` instead for iOS 5.0. This at least gave me more than one app to open the document in.

For **[1]** I agree with the others that this isn't possible as of yet.